# How to put focus on second button on "org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.MessageDialog"

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

I am trying to display a message dialog using the below code :

```
MessageDialog dialog = new MessageDialog(shell, "My Title", null,
             "Are you Sure?", MessageDialog.CONFIRM, 
              new String[] { "Yes","No" }, 0);
```

The only problem is when the message dialog get displayed it shows the focus on the `"Yes"` button so if the user hits enter by default `"Yes"` gets pressed.
**How can i put focus on the "No" button** so that when ever user hits enter "No" gets pressed.

**Please Note** that  I don't want to change the order of Buttons. it should be first Yes and Than No.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set the last constructor argument to the index of the button you wish to be the default.
According to the Javadoc:

```
public MessageDialog(Shell parentShell,
                 String dialogTitle,
                 Image dialogTitleImage,
                 String dialogMessage,
                 int dialogImageType,
                 String[] dialogButtonLabels,
                 int defaultIndex)
```

**defaultIndex** - the index in the button label array of the default button