# How to change the order of buttons of a JFace MessageDialog?

Tags: java, dialog, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

I have an RCP Application where I need a confirmation dialog. I previously used `MessageDialog.openConfirm(getShell(), DIALOG_TITLE, DIALOG_MESSAGE)`, but this is setting the focus on the OK button by default. What I want is to set the default focus on the Cancel button.

So I tried the way of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13375627/902358), and did it like this:

```
MessageDialog dialog = new MessageDialog(getShell(), DIALOG_TITLE, null, 
                DIALOG_MESSAGE, MessageDialog.CONFIRM, 
                new String[] { "Cancel", "OK" }, 0);
```

So I expect the Dialog to show first the Cancel button, then the OK button, and set the focus on the Cancel button at index 0.

However, what I get is this:

[image: Confirmation Dialog]

The focus is on the Cancel button as I expected. But for some reason, the MessageDialog switched the order of buttons, so that OK is now the first button and Cancel is the second.

Is there any way to change the order of buttons, so that I have first Cancel and then OK, like in the default confirmation dialog, and still have the focus on Cancel?

Comment: Just wondering: isn't the "button order" something that might depend on the actual UI theme you are using? Besides: most UIs I recall ... would show the OK button left, and Cancel on the right hand side. I would find it counter intuitive if you reversed that order. ( What I am saying is: be careful and very precise when arranging UI elements )

Comment: Some platforms move the Default button to the rightmost (or leftmost) position.

Comment: Not sure what is the "default" for my OS (Ubuntu). But I know that the button order I got here is exactly the opposite from what I got using the `MessageDialog.openConfirm(getShell(), DIALOG_TITLE, DIALOG_MESSAGE)`. That makes me think that this (first Cancel, then OK) is the actual default order and the custom MessageDialog screws it up.

Comment: Tested your code here on Windows 7 and it works just fine. I can change the button order and I can change the default selection.

Comment: @greg-449 I see, so the reason could be that no matter what the order in my array is, the system will always place the button most-left that has the default focus. Does this mean there is no way to achieve <Cancel (selected)> <OK (not selected)> ?

Comment: I use Mac OS X and it will always move the default button. I don't know about Ubuntu.

Comment: I can test it on Linux Mint (based on Ubuntu) when I get home and get back to you if that would be helpful.

Comment: @Terry Funny enough, you seem to be right, I can't get cancel on the left and selected... How weird.

Comment: Did you guys found any solution for this? I'm stuck in the exact same issue.